# GCD (Greatest Common Divisor) for two 16-bit numbers

Tags: assembly, 8051, greatest-common-divisor, 8-bit

The goal here is to find GCD for two 16-bit numbers stored in little-endian notation. The numbers are stored in the following memory cells:

- first number: 0x3000-0x3001
- seconds number: 0x4000-0x4001
- the result should go into: 0x5000-0x5001

The following example works for 8-bit numbers:

```
ORG 0000H

MOV 30H, #09
MOV 40H, #06
MOV A, 30H
MOV B, 40H
CJNE A, B, next
LJMP stop

next:
  JNC loop
  MOV A, R2
  MOV B, R1
  
loop:
  MOV R3, B
  DIV AB
  MOV A, R3  
  MOV R7, B
  CJNE R7, #00H, loop
  
stop:
  MOV 50H, A
       
END
```

**Questions:** How can I modify this code to operate on two 16-bit numbers? Do I need to operate on individual bytes and then use data pointer (`DPTR`) to load/move them to the desired memory cells?

(I'm using µVision IDE)

Comment: 8051 doesn't have a fast multiplier/divider so [this GCD algorithm](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/17401/1981) would be much better. It uses only `% 2` and `* 2` so it can be easily done for large integers

Comment: Think about what you have learned in primary school: Can you use single digit division to divide numbers with two digits? -- And yes, you need to use `DPTR` to access the memory cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to calculate the Greatest Common Divisor is to use [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Euclid%27s_algorithm). To get the GCD of two 16-bit numbers would require to scale up the very limited `DIV AB` we have on 8051. It's not impossible, but I have chosen to use an algorithm that does not need division at all.

### The binary GCD algorithm

We can avoid the 8051's limited division capabilities and use an algorithm that replaces modulus calculation by a series of shifts and subtractions. Below is how the [Binary GCD algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm) looks like in BASIC:

```
Procedure BinaryGCD
  ; Calculates R% = GCD(A%,B%)
  If A%=0 Or B%=0 Then
    R% = 1
  Else
    C% = 0
    While Even(A%) And Even(B%)
      Inc C%
      A% = Shr(A%,1)
      B% = Shr(B%,1)
    Wend
    Do
      While Even(A%)
        A% = Shr(A%,1)
      Wend
      While Even(B%)
        B% = Shr(B%,1)
      Wend
      Exit If A%=B%
      If A%>B% Then
        Sub A%,B%
      Else
        Sub B%,A%
      Endif
    Loop
    R% = Shl(A%,C%)
  Endif
Return
```

#### Implementation notes

The numbers that are stored in external memory are copied to the Bit Address Area in the internal memory. Why is this? Using the internal memory avoids the troubles of having to manipulate 16-bit addresses all the time. And using the Bit Address Area specifically, allows writing efficient code for testing even/odd conditions. Storing outside of the Bit Address Area would require more bytes and more cycles, not to mention that it would clobber the accumulator. Compare:

```
; Multiprecision number starts at 58h (not bit addressable)
MOV     A, #1
ANL     A, 58h
JNZ     IsOdd
; Uses 6 bytes and consumes 4 cycles

; Multiprecision number starts at 28h (bit addressable)
JB      64, IsOdd
; Uses 3 bytes and consumes 2 cycles
```

Please notice that my program can work with unsigned multiprecision numbers ranging from byte to qword and everything in between. I first created a series of handy subroutines to deal with the multibyte numbers. Many of these subroutines are called one time and could thus easily be inlined also. For the benefit of producing a readable program, I chose not to do that.

#### The subroutines

**IN()**
For every subroutine the `R0`, `R1`, and `DPTR` registers are, on input, pointers to the start of the involved numbers (least significant byte since this is little endean).

**OUT()**
On returning from *mpLoad* and *mpStore*, both `R1` and `DPTR` will have advanced so as to enable processing adjacent items without having to reload pointer registers.
On returning from *mpTest* the accumulator `A` is important. If `A` is zero then the submitted number is zero.
On returning from *mpCmp* the accumulator `A` and the carry flag `C` are important. If `A` is zero then the submitted numbers are equal to each other. Else, a clear `C` indicates that the first number (`@R0`) is greater then the second number (`@R1`), and vice versa for a set `C`.

**MOD()**
Here are listed all the registers that were used by the subroutine but don't return a documented value.

```
; Copies a multiprecision number from external memory to internal memory
; IN(R1,DPTR) OUT(R1,DPTR) MOD(A,R2)
mpLoad:
  MOV     R2, #MPC
Load:
  MOVX    A, @DPTR
  MOV     @R1, A
  INC     DPTR
  INC     R1
  DJNZ    R2, Load
  RET

; Copies a multiprecision number from internal memory to external memory
; IN(R1,DPTR) OUT(R1,DPTR) MOD(A,R2)
mpStore:
  MOV     R2, #MPC
Store:
  MOV     A, @R1
  MOVX    @DPTR, A
  INC     DPTR
  INC     R1
  DJNZ    R2, Store
  RET

; Doubles a multiprecision number
; IN(R1) OUT() MOD(A,R1,R2)
mpShl:
  MOV     R2, #MPC
  CLR     C
Shl:
  MOV     A, @R1
  RLC     A
  MOV     @R1, A
  INC     R1
  DJNZ    R2, Shl
  RET

; Halves a multiprecision number
; IN(R1) OUT() MOD(A,R2)
mpShr:
  MOV     R2, #MPC
  MOV     A, R1
  ADD     A, R2   ; -> C == 0
  MOV     R1, A
Shr:
  DEC     R1
  MOV     A, @R1
  RRC     A
  MOV     @R1, A
  DJNZ    R2, Shr
  RET

; Tests if a multiprecision number is zero
; IN(R1) OUT(A) MOD(R1,R2)
mpTest:
  MOV     R2, #MPC
  MOV     A, #0
Test:
  ORL     A, @R1
  INC     R1
  DJNZ    R2, Test
  RET

; Compares two multiprecision numbers
; IN(R0,R1) OUT(A,C) MOD(R0,R1,R2)
mpCmp:
  MOV     R2, #MPC
  MOV     A, R1
  ADD     A, R2
  MOV     R1, A
  MOV     A, R0
  ADD     A, R2   ; -> C == 0
  MOV     R0, A
Cmp:
  DEC     R0
  DEC     R1
  MOV     A, @R0
  SUBB    A, @R1
  JNZ     CmpRet
  DJNZ    R2, Cmp
CmpRet:
  RET

; Subtracts two multiprecision numbers
; IN(R0,R1) OUT() MOD(A,R0,R1,R2)
mpSub:
  MOV     R2, #MPC
  CLR     C
Sub:
  MOV     A, @R0
  SUBB    A, @R1
  MOV     @R0, A
  INC     R0
  INC     R1
  DJNZ    R2, Sub
  RET
```

#### The main code

You can easily turn this into a fully fledged program.

```
MPC     EQU 2              ; Number of bytes per number aka precision
NumX    EQU 20h            ; Internal memory storage address for first number
NumY    EQU 28h            ; Internal memory storage address for second number
; -------------------------
  MOV     R1, #NumX
  MOV     DPTR, #3000h     ; External memory storage address for first number
  LCALL   mpLoad
  MOV     R1, #NumY
  MOV     DPTR, #4000h     ; External memory storage address for second number
  LCALL   mpLoad
; -------------------------
  MOV     R3, #MPC
  MOV     R0, #NumX
  MOV     R1, #NumX
  LCALL   mpTest           ; -> A
  JZ      SetOne
  MOV     R1, #NumY
  LCALL   mpTest           ; -> A
  JNZ     Begin
SetOne:
  INC     A                ; 0 -> 1, 255 -> 0, 255 -> 0, ...
  MOV     @R0, A
  MOV     A, #255
  INC     R0
  DJNZ    R3, SetOne
  SJMP    Copy
; -------------------------
Begin:
  MOV     R3, #0           ; Bits
While1:
  JB      0, While3        ; Jump if NumX[bit0] == 1
  JB      64, While2       ; Jump if NumY[bit0] == 1
  INC     R3               ; Bits++
  MOV     R1, #NumX
  LCALL   mpShr            ; X >> 1
  MOV     R1, #NumY
  LCALL   mpShr            ; Y >> 1
  SJMP    While1
; -------------------------
While2:
  JB      0, While3        ; Jump if NumX[bit0] == 1
  MOV     R1, #NumX
  LCALL   mpShr            ; X >> 1
  SJMP    While2
; - - - - - - - - - - - - -
While3:
  JB      64, Compare      ; Jump if NumY[bit0] == 1
  MOV     R1, #NumY
  LCALL   mpShr            ; Y >> 1
  SJMP    While3
; - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Compare:
  MOV     R0, #NumX
  MOV     R1, #NumY
  LCALL   mpCmp            ; -> A C
  JZ      Equal
  MOV     R0, #NumX
  MOV     R1, #NumY
  JNC     Minus            ; Do (X - Y)
  MOV     R0, #NumY
  MOV     R1, #NumX
Minus:
  LCALL   mpSub            ; Did (X - Y) or (Y - X)
  SJMP    While2
; -------------------------
Equal:
  MOV     A, R3            ; Bits
  JZ      Copy
Scale:                     ; X << Bits
  MOV     R1, #NumX
  LCALL   mpShl            ; X << 1
  DJNZ    R3, Scale
; -------------------------
Copy:
  MOV     R1, #NumX
  MOV     DPTR, #5000h     ; External memory storage address for resulting number
  LCALL   mpStore
; -------------------------
EXIT:
  NOP
  SJMP $

; Here you add the subroutines

END
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need to add the subroutines at the top? I couldn't compile it so I had to change `MOV` to  `MOVX` for `DPTR` and it was also complaining about some reserved keywords. I don't also get any results in `#5000h` and there seems to be some endless loop.

Comment: @HTF The subroutines go below the main code (see edit). The `MOVX` is my bad, sorry. If you had to change some labels because they're treated as reserved keywords, I would suspect those changes first when confronted with an unexplicable endless loop. Just curious: what are those 'reserved keywords' ? Also, what do you get when one or both inputs are zero? Does it read **1** at 5000h (external) and 20h (internal)?

Comment: OK, so the reserved keywords were `Shl` and `Shr`. Yes, it reads 1 at `5000h` (external) and `20h` (internal). It looks like we don't actually set any values in `3000h` and `4000h` so that should be 0 instead (gcd(0, 0) = 0)? When I tested with `3000h = 0x9, 3001h = 0x0` and `4000h = 0x3, 4001h = 0x0` I got the correct result (`5000h = 0x3, 5001h = 0x0`) but `3000h = 0x12, 3001h = 0x34` and `4000h = 0x0, 4001h = 0x0` show 0 instead of 0x12, 0x34 in 5000h, 5001h respectively?

Comment: @HTF I was kind of expecting that you would add the part that sets up the input parameters (at 3000h and 4000h) yourself, just like you had done in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65480542/add-two-32-bit-numbers-using-8-bit-registers). These are the results that you should get: GCD(0,0) = 1, GCD(9,3) = 3, GCD(0x3412,0x0000) = 1. If any of the inputs is zero, the result must read 1. The number 0 can never be a valid Greatest Common **Divisor** (Division by zero is not allowed).

Comment: @HTF Start your programs with a suitable `ORG` directive like `ORG 0`, clear the Program Status Word `PSW` with `MOV 0D0h, #0` (selecting Register Bank 0), and especially in programs that have to use the stack (`LCALL`,...) set the StackPointer `SP` to somewhere safe like `MOV 81h, #6Fh` (using the 16 bytes from 70h to 7Fh.

Comment: Thanks. I was guided by the results from Python (`math.gcd`). I agree with GCD(0,0) = 1 but for the second example, shouldn't that be GCD(a,0) = a?

Comment: @HTF I've seen GCD(0,0)= **1** but also GCD(0,0)= **0**. I've seen GCD(a,0)= **1** but also GCD(a,0)= **a**. The world doesn't agree on this. It's purely a matter of definition (i). Therefore, go with the flow and adopt the definition that is used in the environment that you're in. It's not worth starting a religuous war on this! (i) `GCD(a,0)=|a|` is used as the base case in Euclid's algorithm. Very convenient so as to avoid division by zero. But in an algorithm that does not depend on true division, that same base case need not persist.